# Perform count on a range of bits in boost dynamic_bitset

Tags: c++, boost-dynamic-bitset

I'm using `boost::dynamic_bitset` to store a large number of bits. I need to count the number of bits set but only on a part of the bitset at a time. The `count` function which boost provides doesn't take a range as parameter. I don't want to modify my original bitset. One option is to use `>>` operator, keep only the bits I need and then use the `count` function on that duplicate bitset but there is an overhead of duplicate bitset creation.

Can anyone suggest any other method to achieve this? Please note I'm focusing on `count` method as it's optimized for performance.